# Using DSLJson instead of Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

As checked for the case of get Object from Json value, DslJson is faster Jackson so should we use DslJson instead of JackSon?

B/c as I saw that in many online document, it looks Jackson more popular than Dsljson so if it faster, why this API is not popular? There have any reasons?

My small checker:

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String jsonString = "{\"kind\":\"dog\",\"name\":\"misao\",\"age\":1}";
    byte[] bytes = jsonString.getBytes();
    Pet misa = new Pet("dog", "misa", 1);

    // get object from json String
    // Jackson
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    long currentTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        Pet misao = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Pet.class);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime1); // 680 ms

    long currentTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        Pet misao = mapper.readValue(bytes, Pet.class);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime2); // 623 ms

    // DSLJson
    DslJson<Object> dslJson = new DslJson<Object>();
    long currentTime3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        Pet misao = dslJson.deserialize(Pet.class, bytes, bytes.length);
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime3); // 182 ms
}}
```

Comment: So if it faster in your case - why not? Or what kind of answer you want to get here?

Comment: @Andrei Vinogradov, b/c as I saw that in many online document, it looks Jackson more popular than Dsljson so if it faster, why this API is not popular? There have any reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think DslJson is not so popular, cause many developers prefer to use old known libraries agains new ones. Jackson is known in community for many years, created and improved by many developers, and became a standard solution. DslJson - new library, created by 2 developers, only 2 years old. Maybe in future it will become a new standard solution, but at the moment almost no-one  knows about it (in comparison to Jackson). So if it's stable, suits best your needs and faster - just use it.

Comment: Umh thank for your response. I hope that, the reason does not relate to memory or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

My teammate ran a benchmark test using gson, jackson and dslJson.

1M serialization + deserialization benchmark

### Tool : Time Taken in ms

---

Gson:           4344

Jackson:        3104

DSL Json:       2299

DSLJson is faster compared to jackson.

Comment: How exactly was the test conducted I am curious.

Comment: https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark